# remove part of text in a div using javacript

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I would like to remove part (4 first characters) of a text in a list of span tags (filtered by the class name):

```html
<span class="time">00:00:50</span>
<span class="time">00:01:22</span>
<span class="time">00:02:44</span>
```

I would like to get this:

```html
<span class="time">0:50</span>
<span class="time">1:22</span>
<span class="time">2:44</span>
```

I try some codes using `text.substr(1, 4)` but none of them works.
Could someone help me?

Comment: What did you attempt?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regular expression to match it

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".time").forEach(function (elem) {
  elem.textContent = elem.textContent.match(/[1-9]?\d:\d\d$/)[0];
});
```

```html
<span class="time">00:00:50</span>
<span class="time">00:01:22</span>
<span class="time">00:02:44</span>
```

substr if it will always be X:XX

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".time").forEach(function (elem) {
  elem.textContent = elem.textContent.substr(-5);
});
```

```html
<span class="time">00:00:50</span>
<span class="time">00:01:22</span>
<span class="time">00:02:44</span>
```

Comment: thanks mate, works flawless, really glad for you help!